# Ignore date in a string with numbers using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, date, match

I have a little Problem.

i use `[0-9\,.]*`
to finde a decimal in a string.
And `([^\s]+)` to find the text behind the first number.

The string looks normally like this. 1 number a text and than a date:

1.023,45 stück

24.05.10

but sometimes I had just the date and then i become 240510 as decimal.
And sometimes I had just the decimal.

How should I modify the regex to find the date if existing and remove it?
And then look for a decimal an select this if existing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer

1. Check for the date first and remove the match from the string

   `([0-9]{1,2}\.){2}[0-9]{1,2}`
2. Find the number using your original regex

   `[0-9\,.]*`
3. If you need it find the unit of quantity (assuming that you will only have it as lower case with u Umlaut)

   `([a-zü]+)`

See http://regexe.de/ (German) and http://www.regexr.com/ (English) for some useful information and tools for dealing with regex.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest matching the number in a more restricted way (1-3 digits, then `.` + `3 digits` groups if any, and a decimal separator with digits, optional).

```
(?s)(?<number>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)\s+(.*?)(?:$|\n|(?<date>\d{2}\.?`\d{2}\.?(?:\d{4}|\d{2})))
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)(%3f%3cnumber%3e%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d)*(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b)%3f)%5cs%2b(.*%3f)(%3f%3a%24%7c%5cn%7c(%3f%3cdate%3e%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%3f%5cd%7b2%7d%5c.%3f(%3f%3a%5cd%7b4%7d%7c%5cd%7b2%7d)))&i=1.023%2c45+st%c3%bcck+24.05.10%0d%0a1.023%2c45+st%c3%bcck+%0d%0a24.05.10&o=m)

The number will be held in `${number}`, and the date in `${date}`. If the string starts with something very similar to a date (6 or 8 digits with optional periods), it won't be captured. If the date format is known (say, the periods are always present), remove the `?`s from `\.?`s.

`(?s)` at the beginning will force the period `.` to match a new line (maybe it is not necessary).